# When trying to delete data in SQL receive following error. XML parsing: line 1, character 39, unable to switch the encoding

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Trying to remove certain data from a table, and when I run the following delete statement I get the error below.

```
delete from table
where type  in (2)
```

Error

> Msg 9402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> XML parsing: line 1, character 39, unable to switch the encoding

Comment: Does `table` have a trigger ?

Comment: Yes, the table has two triggers. One is an update and one is a delete trigger. Also I should mention this is a view table.

Comment: The problem is in one of the triggers. Usually this error indicates that you are trying to update a non-unicode column with unicode xml - does your xml have utf-16 encoding?

Comment: you can disable trigger and delete the data, if you are sure about what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you use names like table and type as table names and column names you should write them in brackets like:

```
delete from [table] where [type] in (2)
```

Comment: The table name is not table, I just didn't put the table name there. Thanks for the input, but this did not solve the issue.